Using keys to activate buttons in Windows Forms
I am writing an application in C# .Net that is a semi-automatic test program, i.e., after a lot of operator involvement I take data automatically.
The operators want keyboard shortcuts.
Because of the operator interaction, I am already trapping a lot of keyboard activity. I have a function to kick off the test and the button simply calls that function. But if I trap a key:
if (e.Control && (e.KeyCode == Keys.Z))
{
    if (button1.Enabled == true)
    {
        // Ready for test
        DoButton();
        textBox2.Text = "Pressed Ctrl-Z";
        Application.DoEvents();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // Test button disabled, test in progress, make this an "any key"
        e.Handled = false;
    }
    return;
}

Obviously, the handler will pause for the duration of the test. Is having "nested" key handler calls a problem?
I did try Button.PerformClick(), but that behaved in the same way, not returning until the button handler has completed:
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
{

    if (button1.Enabled == true)
    {
        // Ready for test
        button1.PerformClick();
        Clicked = true;
        
        textBox2.Text = "Pressed F1";
        Application.DoEvents();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // Test button disabled, test in progress, make this an "any key"
        e.Handled = false;
    }
    return;
}

I know I can start a Task, but because of the operator involvement and a lot of DataGridViews, I will be doing a lot of Invoking, which seems to be defeating the purpose.
Is there any other way to do it?
(I would like multiple shortcuts, so I don't know that the & trick will work)
More Info:
The test routine should only be run once, i.e., not re-entrant. That is why I check for the button being enabled, to prevent the operator from accidentally running the routine again.
During the routine, there is a lot of interaction with the operator, since they have to enter some numbers which are placed in a DataGridView, pause to reset some conditions and other things. Note that I do not use pop ups or requesters, the operator simply enters numbers or letters in the keyboard, or after setting new conditions hits the "any" key.

Not clear whether the procedure that's executed when the accelerator is activated should be synchronous or asynchronous. Can the user activate that accelerator again, while the current procedure is running? Should the UI be responsive in meantime (you can do something else), or should be blocked, to forcibly prevent other actions from being triggered? -- Add the information to the body of the question

If I understand your intent, you probably want to disable the buttons while a test is running regardless of whether invoked by a click or by a shortcut. And since it sounds as though you need to do some asynchronous things (i.e. without blocking), the MRE below shows how to use BeginInvoke and async lambdas in order to do that without resorting to Application.DoEvents().
As far as shortcuts go, one of the easiest ways to make a hot key is to use the ampersand in conjunction with the button text, for example &Run. Then, pressing the [ALT] key will make the shortcuts visible, and pressing [Alt] + R will raise the click event on the button (whichever character follows the ampersand, so R&un would activate on [Alt] + U instead). This is a built-in feature of `Button``.
Nested buttons are shown at the end.

Minimal Reproducible Example

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttonRun.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            BeginInvoke(async() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    EnableButtons(false);
                    CurrentCommandContext = new CommandContext();
                    textBox.Text = "RunningText" + Environment.NewLine;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(500);
                        textBox.AppendText($"Phase {i}{Environment.NewLine}");
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    EnableButtons(true);
                }
            });
        };
        buttonClose.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                if (DialogResult.OK == MessageBox.Show("Application is exiting!", "Alt-C Detected", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel))
                {
                    BeginInvoke(()=>Close());
                }
            });
        };
    }

    private void EnableButtons(bool enabled)
    {
        foreach (Button button in Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            button.Enabled = enabled;
        }
    }
}


Modifier Key Combinations
For an expanded palette of key combinations, the IMessageFilter interface is easy to implement for a Form and is ideal for this because it can hook the KeyDown message regardless of which child control on the Form currently has the focus.
Here, the example is expanded to include [Control] + R and  [Control] + C.
public partial class MainForm : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        Disposed += (sender, e) => Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
        buttonRun.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            BeginInvoke(async() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    EnableButtons(false);
                    CurrentCommandContext = new CommandContext();
                    textBox.Text = "RunningText" + Environment.NewLine;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(500);
                        textBox.AppendText($"Phase {i}{Environment.NewLine}");
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    EnableButtons(true);
                }
            });
        };
        buttonClose.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                if (DialogResult.OK == MessageBox.Show("Application is exiting!", "Alt-C Detected", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel))
                {
                    BeginInvoke(()=>Close());
                }
            });
        };

        Shortcuts = new Dictionary<Keys, Action>
        {
            { Keys.Control | Keys.R, ()=> buttonRun.PerformClick() },
            { Keys.Control | Keys.C, ()=> buttonClose.PerformClick() },
        };
    }

    private void EnableButtons(bool enabled)
    {
        foreach (Button button in Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            button.Enabled = enabled;
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<Keys, Action> Shortcuts { get; }

    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
                Keys keyData = (Keys)(int)m.WParam | Control.ModifierKeys;
                if (Shortcuts.TryGetValue(keyData, out var action))
                {
                    action();
                    return true;
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}


Complete with Nested Commands

Is having "nested" key handler calls a problem?

No it is not, but it will help if you maintain an awaitable CommandContext

public partial class MainForm : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        Disposed += (sender, e) => Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
        buttonRun.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            BeginInvoke(async() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    CurrentCommandContext = new CommandContext();
                    textBox.Text = "RunningText" + Environment.NewLine;
                    var buttonArray = new[] { radioPhase1, radioPhase2, radioPhase3 };
                    foreach (var button in buttonArray) button.Checked = false;
                    EnableButtons(false);
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        CurrentCommandContext = new CommandContext();
                        BeginInvoke(() =>
                        {
                            var button = buttonArray[i];
                            button.Enabled = true;
                            button.PerformClick();
                            button.Enabled = false;
                        });
                        await CurrentCommandContext;
                    }
                    CurrentCommandContext = null;
                }
                finally
                {
                    EnableButtons(true);
                }
            });
        };
        radioPhase1.Click += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            textBox.AppendText($"Running {(sender as Control)?.Text}{Environment.NewLine}");
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            ReleaseCurrentCommandContext();
        };
        radioPhase2.Click += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            textBox.AppendText($"Running {(sender as Control)?.Text}{Environment.NewLine}");
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            ReleaseCurrentCommandContext();
        };
        radioPhase3.Click += async(sender, e) =>
        {
            textBox.AppendText($"Running {(sender as Control)?.Text}{Environment.NewLine}");
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            ReleaseCurrentCommandContext();
        };
        buttonClose.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                var caption = CurrentCommandContext is null ? "Warning" : "Alt-C Detected";
                if (DialogResult.OK == MessageBox.Show("Application is exiting!", caption, MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel))
                {
                    BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        Close();
                        ReleaseCurrentCommandContext();
                    });
                }
                else ReleaseCurrentCommandContext();
            });
        };

        Shortcuts = new Dictionary<Keys, Action>
        {
            { Keys.Control | Keys.R, ()=> buttonRun.PerformClick() },
            { Keys.Control | Keys.C, ()=>
            {
                CurrentCommandContext = new CommandContext();
                buttonClose.PerformClick();
            } },
        };
    }

    private void ReleaseCurrentCommandContext()
    {
        if( CurrentCommandContext != null )
        {
            CurrentCommandContext.Release();
            CurrentCommandContext = null;
        }
    }

    private void EnableButtons(bool enabled)
    {
        foreach (var button in Controls.OfType<ButtonBase>())
        {
            button.Enabled = enabled;
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<Keys, Action> Shortcuts { get; }

    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
                Keys keyData = (Keys)(int)m.WParam | Control.ModifierKeys;
                if (Shortcuts.TryGetValue(keyData, out var action))
                {
                    action();
                    return true;
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Manage asynchronicity.
    /// </summary>
    CommandContext? CurrentCommandContext { get; set; }
}


/// <summary>
/// Manage asynchronicity.
/// </summary>
public class CommandContext
    : EventArgs  // Bonus - Be able to fire any context as an EventArgs e (and potentially await on the server side)
{
    private SemaphoreSlim _busy { get; } = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
    public TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter()
    {
        return _busy
        .WaitAsync()        // Do not use the Token here
        .GetAwaiter();
    }
    internal void Release() => _busy.Release();
}

